# AWS Cloudfront PreconditionFailed Error In lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an Lambda which is used to add Cloudfront Domain and Route 53 Record, In AWS for provided Domain Name.

Consider: "abc.zoro.com" is My website i have provided it as an input, then Lambda will add Route53 Record which is working fine, but when lambda tries to add Domain in distribution then it trigger following error.

**PreconditionFailed: An error occurred (PreconditionFailed) when calling the UpdateDistribution operation: The request failed because it didn't meet the preconditions in one or more request-header fields.**

For Further Investigation i found the the issue might be with E-TAG but, the E-TAG is fetched via event. I checked one Issue on Github, the issue is related to terraform but Error Message is same.
[Github Error](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/19529)

Here is my Code where i am facing issue.

```
def cloudfront(event):
    client = boto3.client('cloudfront')

    response = client.get_distribution(
        Id='CFN_Distribution_ID'
    )
    Config= response["Distribution"]["DistributionConfig"]
    alias = response["Distribution"]["DistributionConfig"]["Aliases"]
    if event['name'] not in alias["Items"]:
        alias["Quantity"]=alias["Quantity"]+1
        alias["Items"].append(event['name'])
        ETAG = response['ETag'] 

        response=client.update_distribution(
            DistributionConfig = Config,
            Id='CFN_Distribution_ID',
            IfMatch=ETAG
        )
```

Can anyone help me regarding this.